# Springer template problem

Tags: pdftex, dvi-mode

I have installed the Springer template for monograph [svmono](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/svmono.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-491898-0), following this [article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages), using the command line interface in linux. But something strange happens. If I use `latex`, everything compiles fine, but the `dvi` output is like a "zipped" text, namely a sequence of meaningless characters. If I use `pdflatex` to compile it (disregarding some minor errors) the output is almost perfect. What could be causing this? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a font problem. Hard to say without a minimal working example http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that Do you have to use latex? Otherwise I'd suggest to be pragmatic and just use pdflatex. You can still use pdf2ps or pdftops if you need to hand in a postscript file. The latex->dvi->ps workflow is a bit dated anyway.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It often helps to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. I this case, what are you using to view the dvi file?

Comment: Actually i have not created anything  with this template by my hands. I am tring to compile the example book.tex in the tamplate package.
Of course i can use pdflatex, but i would like to understand what happens.

Comment: @emanuele: In order for us to identify the problem, we need to be able to recreate it, or you need to supply more information regarding the difference. For example, "some little errors" provide no context nor does it describe *what* errors you received. I downloaded [`svmono`](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/svmono.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-491898-0), and was able to compile with both `latex` and `pdflatex` with only *minor* warnings (not errors). They included bad boxes and a `mathptmx` font warning. So, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: In particular did you convert the dvi file to something else (typically postscript or pdf) or just look at the dvi file directly? Your description sounds almost as if you are looking directly at the dvi file, it is a binary format that needs to be viewed or converted with tools such as xdvi or dvips or dvipdf

Comment: I look dvi with evince, as i always did. @Werner the output is too long. Do i have to post the output anyway?

Comment: @emanuele: In the very least you should post the lines surrounding and including the error message in your `.log` file. You don't have to post *everything*. If you want to post *everything*, perhaps you can use [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) and post a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

For viewing `.dvi` files one need the appropriate program.

- On GNU/Linux boxes you can choose among `xdvi` (uses only standard Xorg libraries), `kdvi` (uses KDE libraries), or Evince (Gnome based).
- On Mac OS X one can use `xdvi` with the system provided X server.
- On Windows usually YAP is used (bundled with MiKTeX).

The best is, however, to convert it into PDF:

```
latex file
dvips file -o
ps2pdf file.ps
```

is the usual pattern. One can do everything by calling

```
simpdftex latex file
```

if running TeX Live.